# ALTER TABLE ON UPDATE CURREN_TIMESTAMP in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

```
ALTER TABLE tabelName ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS columnName TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

I am using this query to create column on update current_timestamp
It is throwing error ERROR:  syntax error at or near "ON"
Thank you all in advance!

Comment: Where [in the manual](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-commands.html) did you find that syntax?

Answer (score 0):

There is no ON UPDATE clause in ALTER TABLE ... ADD COLUMN ... statement. Try instead:

```
ALTER TABLE tableName ADD COLUMN IF NOT EXISTS columnName TIMESTAMP DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Comment: It might be worth adding that you need a trigger for the omitted functionality.